# get json data and pass to PHP string (Here Maps api)

Tags: php, json, here-maps-rest

I am having difficulty getting information from the Here Maps API (which deals with JSON). I am trying to convert the JSON to a string so it can be saved in a database.

Latitude and longitude is most important for my project.

```php
$endereco = 'Rua Canapi 193, Guarulhos, Sao Paulo, Brasil';
$endereco = str_replace(" ", "+", $endereco);
$id = 'devportal-demo-20180625';
$cod = '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ';

// https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=jz23R9Wi89IqwnnxZno0&app_code=g6DikMOdkOUyvGZN3kjW5A&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago
//$json = file_get_contents("http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=$id&app_code=$cod&query=$endereco&gen=9");//
//$json = file_get_contents("https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=$endereco&app_id=$id&app_code=$cod&gen=9");
$json = file_get_contents("https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=$id&app_code=$cod&searchtext=$endereco");

    echo'<pre>';
    //print_r($json = json_decode($json, true));
    print_r($json = json_decode($json));
    echo'</pre>';

//echo $json->{'suggestions'}[0]->{'label'};
//var_dump( $json->{'Response'}{'MetaInfo'}[0]->{'Timestamp'});
```

As you can see I'm trying with the different json url that exists in the documentation page Here maps api and there are other ways but what I want is the one that has latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method as normal way. It'll return an **OBJECT**. To do what you want, you need to pass *true* as second parameter to method return the result as an **ARRAY**.

Also, don't do [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) at the URI parameter, use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method, that will handle all special characters.

Your revised code will be:

```
<?php 
$endereco = "Rua Canapi 193, Guarulhos, Sao Paulo, Brasil";
$id = "here_id";
$cod = "here_cod";

$json = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=" . urlencode ( $id) . "&app_code=" . urlencode ( $cod) . "&searchtext=" . urlencode ( $endereco)), true);

echo "Longitude: " . $json["Response"]["View"][0]["Result"][0]["Location"]["DisplayPosition"]["Longitude"] . "<br />";
echo "Latitude: " . $json["Response"]["View"][0]["Result"][0]["Location"]["DisplayPosition"]["Latitude"] . "<br />";

echo "<pre>";
print_r ( $json);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, @DiBritto. And remember to change your access token (app_id/app_code) at Here, otherwise anyone can use your API key.

Answer (score 1):

I applied your sample data [here](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder).

It creates this rendered url:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Rua%20Canapi%20193%2C%20Guarulhos%2C%20Sao%20Paulo%2C%20Brasil&app_id=jz23R9Wi89IqwnnxZno0&app_code=g6DikMOdkOUyvGZN3kjW5A&
```

and generated this json data:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2018-10-17T03:35:57.353+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "State": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "Street": [
                1
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1
            },
            "MatchType": "pointAddress",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_ySMW7zgrnTcVMzktS0t7FC_xkzM",
              "LocationType": "point",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": -23.46615,
                "Longitude": -46.42356
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": -23.4662,
                  "Longitude": -46.42354
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": -23.4650258,
                  "Longitude": -46.4247855
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": -23.4672742,
                  "Longitude": -46.4223345
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "Rua Canapi, 193, Pimentas, Guarulhos - SP, 07272-060, Brasil",
                "Country": "BRA",
                "State": "SP",
                "City": "Guarulhos",
                "District": "Pimentas",
                "Street": "Rua Canapi",
                "HouseNumber": "193",
                "PostalCode": "07272-060",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Brasil",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "São Paulo",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

First decode the json into an object or array.  There is nothing wrong with object syntax, so I'll show that.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Isolating the `Timestamp` value using object `->` syntax, doesn't require curly braces and quoting, it can look like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X9nRH))

```
echo $obj->Response->MetaInfo->Timestamp;
// 2018-10-17T03:35:57.353+0000
```

As for whatever this is: `$json->{'suggestions'}[0]->{'label'};` that data isn't available.

For the Lat and Long data, here's the full battery:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Debha))

```
echo "Display Position Latitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->DisplayPosition->Latitude;
echo "\nDisplay Position Longitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->DisplayPosition->Longitude;
echo "\nNavigation Position Latitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->NavigationPosition[0]->Latitude;
echo "\nNavigation Position Longitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->NavigationPosition[0]->Longitude;
echo "\nMap View Top Left Latitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->MapView->TopLeft->Latitude;
echo "\nMap View Top Left Longitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->MapView->TopLeft->Longitude;
echo "\nMap View Bottom Right Latitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->MapView->BottomRight->Latitude;
echo "\nMap View Bottom Right Longitude: " , $obj->Response->View[0]->Result[0]->Location->MapView->BottomRight->Longitude;
```

Output:

```
Display Position Latitude: -23.46615
Display Position Longitude: -46.42356
Navigation Position Latitude: -23.4662
Navigation Position Longitude: -46.42354
Map View Top Left Latitude: -23.4650258
Map View Top Left Longitude: -46.4247855
Map View Bottom Right Latitude: -23.4672742
Map View Bottom Right Longitude: -46.4223345
```

Finally, to make your querystring building task simpler/cleaner, use `http_build_query()`:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U8ZR8))

```
$data = [
    'searchtext' => 'Rua Canapi 193, Guarulhos, Sao Paulo, Brasil',
    'app_id' => 'devportal-demo-20180625',
    'app_code' => '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ'
];

$json = file_get_contents('https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?' . http_build_query($data));
```